# How to find out the difference between two times with Moment.js?

Tags: date, momentjs

I am having two times one is sleeping time and another one is wake up time, and I want to find out difference between these two times.

Is there any way to do so? I am using Moment.js.

Comment: `moment.diff` is the method you want.

Comment: its working, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation for momentjs here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```